# Where is the AWS elastic search snapshot taken daily?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

When we create the elasticsearch cluster in AWS, it asks for “Start hour for the daily automated snapshot”. What does this configuration control? Where is the snapshot taken daily? Is it in some S3 bucket or something? Or is it something that’s in backend? If this is in backend, why do they ask us the time? Does taking the snapshot, impacts the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapshot will impacts the performance, so AWS want you set best time that low impacts to your application.

Your snapshot will store to s3 as document.

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html